# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException due to Spannable TextView

Tags: android, textview

I received this crash report in my Google Play Console which I myself never experience and unable to reproduce.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at android.text.method.WordIterator.checkOffsetIsValid (WordIterator.java:380)
  at android.text.method.WordIterator.isBoundary (WordIterator.java:101)
  at android.widget.Editor$SelectionStartHandleView.positionAtCursorOffset (Editor.java:4300)
  at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updatePosition (Editor.java:3736)
  at android.widget.Editor$PositionListener.onPreDraw (Editor.java:2513)
  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw (ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2417)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:6708)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:894)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:696)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:631)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:880)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:815)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:104)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5728)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

The crash report didn't mention which class is causing the crash. My best guess is the follow custom `TextView`.

```
private void customTextView(TextView view) {
        SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                Html.fromHtml(definition[0]));
        spanTxt.append("\n\nExample");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showAlert();
            }
        }, spanTxt.length() -"Example".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
        view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
```

Is there any problem with my custom `TextView`?

Comment: you did set the `click span` on blank space ..why ?

Comment: I would like to make the word "Example" clickable only. My code do not make the \n clickable though. This is the reason causing the crash?

Comment: oops i missed that ..

Comment: but you check that if the clickspan working accurately on the string before the `\n`

Comment: Clicking on the string before \n do not call my ClickableSpan method.

Comment: My guess is in some scenario your definition[0] that is your spantext- your example.length returns you negative value in such case you are getting invalid offset and exception is being raised.try to reproduce by taking small string or blank string as your span text for temporary to check you are getting same crash log or not.

Comment: @JayShah On checking the source for `SpannableStringBuilder` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java#683), I found that if the range (end < start) is invalid then the method will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, [checkout here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/nougat-mr1.2-release/core/java/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.java#1256)

Answer (score 2):

I have removed your **Html.fromHtml(definition[0])** and **\n\n**. Then it worked well. Please test these two things if these are coming or not.

```
private void customTextView(TextView view) {
    SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder("Testing");
    spanTxt.append("Example");
    spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Log.e("tag","show click");
        }
    }, spanTxt.length() -"Example".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
    view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Cross check your text if it coming for not. This one **Html.fromHtml(definition[0])**. Not sure why you using **\n\n** it will goes to next line.

Check these two things. Others are working perfectly.

Thanks.

Comment: But this string is in HTML code, I need to use `Html.fromHtml`. I need to use \n\n as well to bring the next to next 2 line.

Comment: It's working with html and \n\n too. Just  put something else irrespective of this `definition[0]`. Probably your **definition[0]** could be null.

Answer (score 2):

The exception refers to [this line](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/method/WordIterator.java#383) in AOSP.
I think this line in your code:

```
spanTxt.length() -"Example".length()
```

is creating a negative or otherwise invalid offset value (probably because you're appending `"\n\nExample"` instead? Is there a way you could just embed that example string in your resource string?

Answer (score 2):

Since not all of your code is shared here, it is not obvious to me where the actual issue is. The exception seems to be caused by the cursor position within a selectable TextView in a Choreographer being out of bounds. From the `WordIterator.java` source code I see:

```
private void checkOffsetIsValid(int offset) {
   if (!(mStart <= offset && offset <= mEnd)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid offset: " + (offset) +
           ". Valid range is [" + mStart + ", " + mEnd + "]");
   }
}
```

I personally have not run into this problem but there could be an issue with Android clearing the TextView selection when calling setText as is explained (with some workarounds) in this post [IllegalArgumentException while selecting text in Android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821008/illegalargumentexception-while-selecting-text-in-android-textview)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with spantext code. Coding is working fine if removed variable - `Html.fromHtml(definition[0])`

There might be issue with `Html.fromHtml(definition[0])`

Comment: But this string is in HTML code, I need to use `Html.fromHtml`.

Comment: can you share the out put of `Html.fromHtml(definition[0])`

Comment: Just some string with <p>, <b>, <br> tag.